# How do I use my Google account when I have a FIDO U2F Key attached?

Tags: security, google-account

I have recently attached a FIDO U2F Key to my Google Account to make it more secure. 
How can I now actually log into my Google Account on Android again?

Whenever I try to log in, it says wrong password, even though I know it is the right password. Does anyone know what is required to get it working again?

Comment: do you try to Login in with Gmail Site on Pc ? and your account can sign in ?

Comment: @Mohsen Of course I can log into my account on PC, because I can stick the FIDO Key into my USB Port.

Comment: What is your exact FIDO U2F key? What is your phone? Which Android version are you running? - - Do you have second-step verification also on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log into GMail after attaching any sort of 2 Factor Auth, one has to create an [Application specific password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en) for use with your Google Account. For that, you have to to the [Authorization Page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) in your Google Account, enter a custom name and google will create a secure password that one can use with any device. This password is only visible once after creation, so if you need to log in again, just create a new one, which is safer than writing it down.

Example:

[image: Screenshot of an example one time password]

Answer (score 2):

Use a application token:

If familiar with Two Factor Auth. /Multi. Factor Auth. on Github or Bitbucket and use a ssh token essentially the  exact same thing.

May I recommend using google authenticator  ---which by default creates  10 OTPs (one time passwords) that can be used if the FIDO is not pre registered.

Comment: I am not going to remove FIDO. My Mail account is linked to various services such as Steam or Netflix and it being hacked is something I need to avoid. Only a physical device can ensure that nobody besides me or at least having access to my house can access my Account. I need a solution that does not involve removing the key and I am actually surprised there is no google article about that.

Comment: I'm not saying stop /don't use a FIDO I'm suggesting using a second factor other than the FIDO to get it properly registered and associated with all those..google authenticator actually supports FIDO "bolt on"  Noneof your business's  inset  is EXACTLY what I'm sugessting I use the same thing + seperate sane sync pass on gmail/ALL things google and  that app token  for github and all other networks / apps.

Comment: Well but you don't need it. No need to make it complicated.