# How to have isolated FIDO access in Android 7.x?

Tags: security, encryption, 7.0-nougat, usability

I know the generic thread  [How do I use my Google account when I have a FIDO U2F Key attached?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/101999/9897) 
I would like to limit the access to two modes, such that creating an isolated access if you do not have the FIDO key connected to your phone

- without YubiKey 4c connected, only basic phone capabilities like in Nokia phones
- with YubiKe 4c Connected, all features allowed

I know that there are some custom applications which try to accomplish similar goals etc [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.sgk.android.app.yubikey&hl=lv). 
However, I think the case requires an OS development approach to succeed. 
I think the security team and OS development team should target the security tweak in current Android systems where they do not offer by default **Android with keys**.

Phone: any Android 7.x phone
Android: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported by default. No maintainer for the feature in Android 7.